# how do I show min and max values from a table in html?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to be able to click on a button and get the min and max values from the text box, the values should show in the final `<td><td>` after every column and row
(I'm kinda new to programming but I don't mind reading and learning, so if someone can point me in the right direction, i'd be glad, I wouldn't mind using some php if it makes it easier) this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<center>
    <h1>TEORIA DE JUEGO</h1>
    <table>
      <tr>
            <td></td>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>A2</td>
        <td>A3</td>
        <td>A4</td>
        <td>MIN</td>
        <tr>
          <td>B1</td>
          <td> <input type = "text" id = "a1b1" value = "" /></td>
          <td><input type = "text" id = "a1b2" value = "" /></td>
          <td><input type = "text" id = "a1b3" value = "" /></td>
          <td><input type = "text" id = "a1b4" value = "" /></td>
          <TD></TD>
        </tr>
        <td>B2</td>
        <td><input type = "text" id = "a2b1" value = "" /></td>
        <td><input type = "text" id = "a2b2" value = "" /></td>
        <td><input type = "text" id = "a2b3" value = "" /></td>
        <td><input type = "text" id = "a2b4" value = "" /></td>
        <TD></TD>
      </tr>
      <td>B3</td>
      <td><input type = "text" id = "a3b1" value = "" /></td>
      <td><input type = "text" id = "a3b2" value = "" /></td>
      <td><input type = "text" id = "a3b3" value = "" /></td>
      <td><input type = "text" id = "a3b4" value = "" /></td>
      <TD></TD>
      <tr>
            <td>B4</td>
            <td><input type = "text" id = "a4b1" value = "" /></td>
            <td><input type = "text" id = "a4b2" value = "" /></td>
            <td><input type = "text" id = "a4b3" value = "" /></td>
            <td><input type = "text" id = "a4b4" value = "" /></td>
            <TD></TD>
          </tr>
          <td>MAX</td>
          <tr>
                <td><button onclick="">Calcular</button></td>
          </tr>
  </center>
```

Comment: I appreciate your willingness to learn PHP. However, if you wish to have the calculation done from `Calcular` you need JavaScript. I suppose technically you could use AJAX, but that's not needed for this problem, and not a beginner subject.

Comment: @Chipster how do I use JavaScript to calculate it?

Comment: Some invalid HTML in there, missing a `</table>`, that `</tr>` before your MAX is wrong. And `<center>` is obsolete.

Comment: Well, [here is a tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript) to get you started. If you still have questions after that, don't hesitate to ask.